# How can I pass variables to post-build actions in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to send an email in a post-build action, with the content set to some results I computed in a build action. I cannot seem to be able to pass variables from the shell code to any post-build actions.

I have tried with EnvInject, but haven't managed to make it work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

As it always happens, I managed to find the solution right after I posted the question.

I managed to solve it by having something like this in the shell script bit:

```
EMAIL_CONTENT=$(cat <<EOF
Some content here.
Some content there.
EOF
)

EMAIL_RECIPIENTS="someone@example.com"    

touch email_properties
echo "EMAIL_CONTENT=${EMAIL_CONTENT}" >> email_properties
echo "EMAIL_RECIPIENTS=${EMAIL_RECIPIENTS}" >> email_properties
```

And then, in the post-build action, I used `Trigger parametrized build on other projects`, with the `Parameters from properties file` option in order to trigger some other job whose only purpose is to email me those credentials. It's a bit of a work around, but it works.

Comment: I have a similar issue here, and if I understand your workaround: you create a property file, through `trigger parameterized build...` to trigger the downstream job. I am able to pass the parameters in the property file to the downstream job, but the email trigger is not able to use it. I use   Script - After Build with trigger script `build.envVars["GO"]  == 'Y'`. How did you make it work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470021/variable-from-a-property-file-used-in-email-trigger-script-in-jenkins

Comment: Really sorry, @Heinz, it's been way too long since I did this. I think there was a field in there like "Load properties from file" and it would just read that `email_properties` file in the email trigger. but I'm sorry, this was way too long ago. :(

Comment: `Trigger parametrized build on other projects` does not seem to exist anymore in Jenkins version 2.190

Comment: @Scott you need to install this plugin http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: If you do not see `Trigger parameterized build on other projects` as a Post-Build action then you may need to install this plugin http://wiki.jenkinsci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

For this example you use the  email_properties as the property file name.

Then in the Parameterized Jenkins build or project that you are calling make sure that the key for your properties file is defined as a String parameter by selecting `This project is parameterized` and filling in the Name. In this case the names for the `String parameters` are EMAIL_CONTENT and EMAIL_RECIPIENTS