# Variable from a property file used in email trigger script in JENKINS

Tags: email, jenkins, build, triggers, properties-file

I have two jobs: Job_a and Job_b. I want to use a variable in Job_a to decide whether an email should be sent in JOb_b.
The simplified jobs:

**In Job_a:**

*Step 1*: Execute Windows batch command:

```
echo GO=Y > testme.txt
```

this will create testme.txt with GO=Y in the workspace.

*Step 2*: Trigger/call builds on other projects:

projects to build: `Job_b`
Parameters from property files: `testme.txt`

**In Job_b:**

*Step 1*:

```
echo Go = %GO%
```

*Post-build Actions*
Editable Email Notification

**triggers**:  Script - After Build 
**trigger script**:

```
build.envVars["GO"]  == 'Y'
```

**Now, run Job_a, no email triggered, while step 1 in Job_b, does print Go = Y**

to prove the trigger script itself is correct, I add a String Parameter in Job_a:

```
Name: GO1
Default Value: Y
```

and change the trigger script in Job_b to:

```
build.envVars["GO1"]  == 'Y'
```

**run Job_a, thus JOb_b as well, and email was sent as expected.**

**it seems that only parameters defined in the upstream job can be used in the email trigger script, parameters in the property file are not available.**

I know I could inject the parameter from the property file in the fly with EnvInject Plugin, and/or with System Groovy script, I can add new parameters, but my build environment is tight controlled, there is no System groovy, no new additional plugin can be installed.

My jenkins version is 1.622

Comment: Use Parameterized Trigger Plugin installed or not, If installed pass the Parameter value from Job_a to Job_b in post build actions.

Comment: @Suresh, I said the parameter was indeed passed from Job_a to Job_b, the problem is the email trigger script can't access it.

Comment: What configuration you did in the editable email?

Answer (score 0):

To share with everyone. I have found what went wrong.

The property file has one line: `GO=Y` 
The parameter 'GO' in the property file created in Job_a IS indeed passed to Job_b.

The groovy test `build.envVars["GO"]  == 'Y'` does not return 'true', thus no email will be sent.

I print the length of the parameters:

```
println build.envVars["GO"].length()

println 'Y'.length()
```

which prints

```
2 
1
```

Apparently, there is a new line carriage appended when we create the contents of the property file with

```
echo GO=Y > testme.txt
```

I have to trim off the new line carriage, so change the trigger script for the editable mail, **Script - After build** to

```
build.envVars["GO"].trim() == 'Y'
```

it works as expected.